# greedy and recursive algorithm for finding shortest path for all nodes in a complete binary tree with node and edge weights

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, greedy

I have a setup like this

The first part of the question is to implement a function that generates a complete binary tree (i.e. two arrays) with a given size as input where the node and edge weights are set randomly between 1 and 20 inclusive.

I wrote the code below for the first part and I need to develop a greedy algorithm and a recursive algorithm for finding the shortest path for all nodes in the tree.

How can I develop greedy and recursive algorithms guys?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randWN(9)));
    int[][] qq=randWE(9);

    for (int[] row : qq)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}

public static int[] randWN(int size)
{
    int[] WN=new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < WN.length; i++) {
        WN[i]=getRandomNumber(1,20);
    }
    return WN;
}
public static int[][] randWE(int size)
{
    int counter=0;
    int iterator=0;
    int[][] WE=new int[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < WE.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < WE[size-1].length; j++) {
            if(j>iterator && counter<2)
            {
                WE[i][j]=getRandomNumber(1,20);
                counter++;
                iterator++;
            }
        }
        counter=0;
    }
    return WE;

}
public static int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
}
```

output of the first part is here

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking for here. A binary tree is a directed acyclic graph (i.e. there are paths from parents to children, but not from children to parents). There is only one path from the root to any given node. If what you mean is you want to find the lowest-cost path to any leaf node, it's a really simple modification to the standard preorder traversal.

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if am mistaken, but your code does not produce a binary tree, but rather a square matrix. How does this represent a complete binary tree?

I think an implementation using a class node with parent and child attributes which in turn are nodes as well, makes more sense?

And then you just follow a greed algorithm to find the shortest path. E.g. recursively traverse the tree, always choosing to cheapest path to the next node, and backtrack once you are at a leaf. Maybe looking up binary trees on wikipedia might help.

Or I missinterpreted something and am completely wrong.

Answer (score -1):

i attached screenshots in the question but it didn't attached sorry for that
 [this is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWQOz.png)

and i finished the first part it has 2 array